# Can't build Vue.js app with Typescript project references

Tags: typescript, vue.js, dependencies, monorepo

I'm attempting to utilize Typescript project references to build a Vue app in a monorepo. My current project structure is as follows:

```
client/
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  src/
    ...

server/
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  src/
    ...

shared/
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  preferences.ts
  permissions.ts
  interfaces/
    ...
```

`client/tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["mocha", "chai", "vuetify", "webpack-env"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["../shared/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "references": [
    { "path": "../shared" }
  ]
}
```

`shared/tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "composite": true
    }
}
```

The only errors I get are when I reference `preferences` or `permissions` in the `shared` folder. A few things to note:

- If I reference something in `shared/interface` from `client`, it doesn't raise any issues. It only raises an issue if I reference a file directly in the root of `shared`.
- Intellisense does *not* detect any issues in vscode.

```
 INFO  Starting development server...
Starting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 7 errors                                                                                                              11:14:37 AM
These dependencies were not found:

* @shared/permission in ./src/router/index.ts, ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Home/Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& and 1 other
* @shared/preference in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Navigation.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&, ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Account/Preferences.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& and 2 others

To install them, you can run: npm install --save @shared/permission @shared/preference
No type errors found
Version: typescript 3.9.9
Time: 6921ms
```

Any ideas on how to fix these errors?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Having the same problem myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What ended up working for me was to configure Webpack (which Vue uses under the hood) to resolve my alias `"@shared"` to the correct path.

To do this, you need to edit your `vue.config.js` like so:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@shared": path.resolve(__dirname, '../shared/dist')
    }
  }
};
```

(Source: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/main/REFERENCES.md#setup-your-codebase-to-consume-the-project)

Notice - just like using [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) - if you specified an `outDir` (`tsconfig.json`) in your `shared` project, you need to point the alias path to the files located in there. For me this meant appending `/dist` to the path.

However, when starting the dev-server I got an error telling me that ESLint is not configured for my `@shared` path (which is correct). So the last thing missing was to exclude my `@shared` path from ESLint. For this, all you need to do is create a `.eslintignore` file in your `client` directory where you point to the `shared` directory:

```
../shared
```

I hope this works for you, even if I might be a little late to the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Murph it's not totally correct. You need to put that settings under the key `configureWebpack`. See https://dev.to/alansolitar/webpack-aliases-in-vue-js-41hp

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29782603)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.